# Media Playback with kurento media server for recorded stream

Tags: kurento

I am exploring kurento media server capability to do fastforward, fastrewind, play, pause for rtsp steam for recorded video file.

1. Does it support mediaplay back?
2. How many simulations stream can be played in a browser + how many stream server can handle?

Quick help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take a moment to read the guidelines for asking questions here in the [Help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help). You're expected to have already done basic research, which include reading the documentation of what you use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PlayerEndpoint` supports only playback at a normal rate. However, it supports: pause, stop, play and seeks (if the video/audio source supports them).

About your second question. We do not have this kind of data, as it depends on the application model you use.

Comment: COuld you guide how the playback of nvr video stream can be done. Please provide some information on this. I have kurento installed and have made my cameras stream through it, now I want to have the playback to be enabled for them. Please help, how this can be done.